# How to populate a UITableView in a UIView without cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I'am dealing with a problem the past few days. I have a UIScrollView in a xib file, in this UIScrollView i put UIViews (as xib too), and in them UIViews i put UITableViews (as xib too). But as a rookie i always populated my UITableView using cellForRowAtindexPath, you return the cell with your wanted text and it's all done, but this time it is not called, so maybe there is another way to populate it ?. As information i'am trying to use CollapseClick as my view. If someone could help me please or have the slightest idea about how to populate it feel free to answer please.

here is my code, i spare you all the xml parsing process. 
.m were i init my UITableView

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    newsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    newsTable.delegate = self;
    //newsTable.dataSource = self;

    myCollapseClick.CollapseClickDelegate = self;
    [myCollapseClick reloadCollapseClick];

    // If you want a cell open on load, run this method:
    [myCollapseClick openCollapseClickCellAtIndex:0 animated:YES];

    /*
     // If you'd like multiple cells open on load, create an NSArray of NSNumbers
     // with each NSNumber corresponding to the index you'd like to open.
     // - This will open Cells at indexes 0,2 automatically

     NSArray *indexArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
     [myCollapseClick openCollapseClickCellsWithIndexes:indexArray animated:NO];
     */
}
```

were i need to return the UIViews with the UITable views

```
-(UIView *)viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:(int)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return test1View;
            break;
        case 1:
            return test2View;
            break;
        case 2:
            return test3View;
            break;
        default:
            return test1View;
            break;
    }
}
```

the good old cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];
    //self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    if (storyIndex == 0 && FlagS)
    {
        NSMutableArray * SIR = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"sizingSheet"];
        NSString * SID = [[SIR objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"sizing_id"];
        NSString *DID = [[SIR objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"data_id"];

        Request = [[restRequestManager alloc]init];
        NSString *SDD = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@", @"sizing_id=", SID, @"&",  @"data_id=", DID];
        NSData* Mimage =  [Request restTestRequesterImage:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com" serviceUri:@"question/Post" parameters:SDD technique:@"POST"];

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:Mimage];
        return cell;
    }

    searchString = @"TH_MEASURE_CATEGORY_";
    str=[category objectAtIndex:storyIndex];
    NSArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

    for (NSString *tempStr in array) {
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {

            lbl1.text = [category objectAtIndex: storyIndex];
            lbl1.text = [lbl1.text substringFromIndex: MIN(20, [lbl1.text length])];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
        }
        else{
            lbl1.text = [category objectAtIndex: storyIndex];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
        }
    }
    return cell;

}
```

and the .h without all the useless stuff

```
@interface MeasuresViewController: UIViewController <CollapseClickDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIView *test1View;
    IBOutlet UIView *test2View;
    IBOutlet UIView *test3View;

    __weak IBOutlet CollapseClick *myCollapseClick;

    IBOutlet UITableView * newsTable;

    BOOL *FlagS;

    UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator;

    CGSize cellSize;


    NSMutableArray * stories;

    NSMutableString * currentCategory, * currentSubcategory, * currentValue, * currentName, * currentSrc;

    NSDictionary *data, *data1, *data2, *data3, *data4;


}

- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL;
-(BOOL)ifStringExists:(NSString *)stringSentToCheck selectYourCheckArray:(NSMutableArray *)SelectedArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *photos;
@property (atomic, strong) NSMutableArray *assets;

@end
```

Comment: Have you set tableview delegate & datasource Methods?? or set link in xib.

Comment: delegates like the delegates you declare in the .h ? i edit with the .h righ now.

Comment: /`/newsTable.dataSource = self;` ??? reomve comment

Comment: Did it few seconds ago, nothing happens still ignoring it and i get a warning it says Assigning to 'id<UITableViewDataSource>' from incompatible type 'MeasuresViewController "const_strong". Is cellForRowAtIndexPath must be declare in a UITableViewController class to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented out the line that sets the data source. If a data source is not set then cellForRowAtIndexPath: will not be called.

Your current viewDidLoad code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    newsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    newsTable.delegate = self;
    //newsTable.dataSource = self;

    myCollapseClick.CollapseClickDelegate = self;
    [myCollapseClick reloadCollapseClick];

    // If you want a cell open on load, run this method:
    [myCollapseClick openCollapseClickCellAtIndex:0 animated:YES];

    /*
     // If you'd like multiple cells open on load, create an NSArray of NSNumbers
     // with each NSNumber corresponding to the index you'd like to open.
     // - This will open Cells at indexes 0,2 automatically

     NSArray *indexArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
     [myCollapseClick openCollapseClickCellsWithIndexes:indexArray animated:NO];
     */
}
```

Change it to

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    newsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    newsTable.delegate = self;
    newsTable.dataSource = self;

    myCollapseClick.CollapseClickDelegate = self;
    [myCollapseClick reloadCollapseClick];

    // If you want a cell open on load, run this method:
    [myCollapseClick openCollapseClickCellAtIndex:0 animated:YES];

    /*
     // If you'd like multiple cells open on load, create an NSArray of NSNumbers
     // with each NSNumber corresponding to the index you'd like to open.
     // - This will open Cells at indexes 0,2 automatically

     NSArray *indexArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
     [myCollapseClick openCollapseClickCellsWithIndexes:indexArray animated:NO];
     */
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my nobbiness but what is datasource ?

Comment: The dataSource tells the UITableView where the data (cells) come from. In your question you have view did load method:

[super viewDidLoad];
    newsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
    newsTable.delegate = self;
    //newsTable.dataSource = self;

simply change that last line so that it is not commented out and cellForRowAtIndexPath should be called.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have uncommented it, and put a little breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath, compile, run, but it doesn't go in cellForRowAtIndexPath, like it doesn't exist.

Comment: I just re-read your question. You said that the table view is being created in the xib? If so, is the newsTable that you are creating in viewDidLoad doing anything? If the table is created in the xib you can right click on it and in the popup there is an option for dataSource. Make sure dataSource is connected to the "File's Owner"

Comment: yes it is called in the xib, yes newsTable is the UITableView in my UIView. Indeed it wasn't connected to the dataSource :3, but i get an exception :3.

Comment: finally got it, i still got a exception :3, but the breakpoint stops and highlights in rowAtIndexPath :D !